# Where in the Garuda Purana is it said that only three Vaishnava Puranas are authoritative in Kali yuga?

Tags: vaishnavism, bhagavata-purana, vishnu-purana, padma-purana, garuda-purana

I read somewhere that Garuda Purana declares that only three Vaishnava Puranas should be considered authoritative in Kali Yuga. By priority they are:-

1. Bhagavata Purana
2. Vishnu Purana
3. Garuda Purana

This contradicts sattva, tamas and rajas division of puranas done by Padma Purana as Padma Purana declares only Vaishnava Puranas as authentic. Garuda Purana however reduces it to only three puranas.

Is it true?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that this is taken from the [Garuda Purana: Brahma (Moksa) Khanda: Chapter 1](https://archive.org/details/GarudaPuranamSanskritEnglish/page/n840/mode/1up):

> The wise declare knowledge to be manifold, consisting of various grades — high, low and middling. All that knowledge is found in the Bhagavata Purana. Hence, Bhagavata is the highest of all Puranas.
>
> The Visnu Purana comes next then comes Garuda. **The three are principal Puranas in the Kali age**.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is in this website 
[https://www.hinduwebsite.com/sacredscripts/puranas/gp/gp.asp on]

Comment: From [How do I write a good answer?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): "Provide context for links. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Answer (score 0):

There are 18 puranas (Satvik, Rajasic, Tamsic)
Garuda purana Brahma Khanda Adhyaya 1 verse 43-45
kalau yuge sarva purāṇamadhye trīṇyeva mukhyāni haripriyāṇi
mukhyaṃ purāṇaṃ hi kalau nṛṇāṃ ca śreyaskaraṃ bhāgavataṃ purāṇam

pūrvaṃ hi sṛṣṭiḥ pratipādyate tra yato hyato bhāgavataṃ paraṃ smṛtam
yasminpurāṇe kathayanti sṛṣṭiṃ hyādau viṣṇorbrahmarudrādikānām

nānārthamevaṃ kathayanti vipra nīcoccarūpaṃ jñānamāhurmahāntaḥ
tenaiva siddhaṃ pravadanti sarvaṃ hyataḥ paraṃ bhāgavataṃ purāṇam

Yes the 6 sattvik  puranas are also great authority but these three are ones which gives the maximum benefit.